# Find the formula for Sn

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find an explicit formula for $s_n$ if $s_0,s_1,s_2....$ is a sequence satisfying the given recurrence relation and initial conditions. I'm trying to figure out how to finish the formula.

$s_n = -8s_{n-1} - 15s_{n-2}, s_0=2, s_1=2$

What I did was

$x^2=-8x -15$
= $x^2+8x+15$
=$(x+5)(x+3)$

$s_0=c_1(-5)^0+c_2(-3)^0 = c_1+c_2$

$s_1=c_1(-5)^1+c_2(-3)^1 = (-5c_1)+(-3c_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done all the hard work.

$$s_n=c_1(-5)^n+c_2(-3)^n$$

Just solve for the arbitrary constants $c_1,c_2$ from the two linear simultaneous equations

$c_1+c_2=s_0=2\  \ \ \ (1)$

$c_1(-5)+c_2(-3)=s_1=2\  \ \ \ (2)$

Answer (score 0):

You look fine so far.  What you have now are the equations $s_0=c_1+c_2$ and $s_1=-5c_1-3c_2$.  This is a system of linear equations, and can be solved for $c_1$ and $c_2$ in terms of $s_0$ and $s_1$.  Solve this system, and you're essentially done.